# Strange behavior of SmtpClient UseDefaultCredentials property

Tags: c#, .net, smtpclient

This morning I discovered some strange behavior of the [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class (.net 3.5). Can't explain if it's the class that is causing it, or the SMTP-server.

The following is happening:

- Instantiating SmtpClient with UseDefaultCredentials **true** and Credentials **null**, no mail send;
- Instantiating SmtpClient with UseDefaultCredentials **false** and Credentials to a valid account, no mail send;
- Instantiating SmtpClient with UseDefaultCredentials **false** and Credentials **null**, mail send succesfully.

In the first two cases the exception message was:

> Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client does not
>   have permissions to send as this sender"

Questions:

- How can I figure out what is causing this behavior?
- Any way to workaround in c#?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Does the *from* field match your user? Perhaps the smtp server is expecting that? (also, I hope the server isn't accepting connections from outside, as it seems auth isn't actually required)

Comment: Think indeed the 'from' user doesn't match with the account in the Credentials property (checking this...). Apart from this, isn't it strange mails can be send without exception if Credentials aren't provided?

Comment: It all depends on how the smtp server is configured. I'd say that's a potential big problem, if a spammer finds that server, it'll end up being black listed. (unless it otherwise doesn't accept mail from external sources.)

Comment: Andrew Barber Checked with the IT department and they confirmed your answer. Problem was solved, thanks!! How can I give you the accept credits?

Comment: I've added an answer. Glad you got it worked out!

Comment: Was having the same issue.  But, I set my client.Credentials = null and client.UseDefaultCredentials = False and it worked.  Don't know why and don't care. lol  It's working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on how the SMTP server is configured, but in this case it seems the problem was that the `from` address did not match the account being used to log into the sending SMTP server. As a result, relaying was rejected.